# autocomplete="off" not working in Microsoft Edge Version 87.0.664.57

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, microsoft-edge

Autocomplete="off" not working in Microsoft Edge latest version (87.0.664.57) in ASPNET.NET MVC app.
I added `$("input:text,form").attr("autocomplete", "off");` globally and it is not working.

Comment: I want to confirm with you whether this issue occurs with any specific fields like the address field or card number for payment? If yes, then it can be possible that information is stored in the Edge browser profile. You can go to the `edge://settings/addresses` and disable the option `Save and fill addresses` and go to the `edge://settings/payments` and disable the option `Save and fill payment info`. If autocomplete shows on all the fields then I suggest you please try to post the sample source code of the form may help to understand the issue in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Using MS Edge on Windows 10, Version 88.0.705.74, it seems that 'gibberish' is the answer. I don't try to explain MS, but all the normal values for the attribute 'autocomplete' fail ('on', 'off', 'true', 'false'). Any type of gibberish value will turn it off, otherwise it will automatically be on. Be sure you put the autocomplete = 'gibberish' in your input element, not the form.